# Alignment for nested matrices

Tags: equations, matrices

I want to get a matrix of arrays, and I cannot make it aligned. I tried blkarray and bmatrix, but none of them works for me. Could somebody help me out?
Code below is what I wrote:

```
a = \left[ 
\begin{array}{c@{}c@{}c}
    \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
      255 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{array}\right] & \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
    0 & 94.5 & 94.5 \\
    \end{array}\right] \\
    \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
    0 & 99 & 0 \\
    \end{array}\right] & \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
    0 & 0 & 9 \\
    \end{array}\right] \\
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation*}
```

And it turn out to be misaligned:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With `nicematrix` package:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    \[
a = 
\begin{bNiceArray}{c@{}ccc@{}c c@{}ccc@{}c}
      [ & 255 & 0  & 0 &]   &   [& 0 & 94.5 & 94.5 &]   \\
      [ &   0 & 99 & 0 &]   &   [& 0 & 0    & 9    &]   \\
\end{bNiceArray}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
By use of `\CodeAfter` and `\SubMatrix` (you need `nicematrix` version 5.10 or newer):

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\[
a =
\begin{bNiceArray}{ccc@{\hspace{1em}}ccc}[margin]
      255 & 0  & 0   &   0 & 94.5 & 94.5 \\[1ex]
        0 & 99 & 0   &   0 & 0    & 9    \\
\CodeAfter
\SubMatrix[{1-1}{1-3}] \SubMatrix[{1-4}{1-6}]
\SubMatrix[{2-1}{2-3}] \SubMatrix[{2-4}{2-6}]
\end{bNiceArray}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome!!!  Just a reminder for others, I cannot compile with this code for two things:1.texlive should be latest enough ([at least 2019](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102115/discussion-on-question-by-tatty-man-nicematrix-does-not-seem-to-work-ubuntu-1)); 2. format letters shoule be capital ones ("L","R","C")

Comment: @吕和瑾, I used recent version of `nicematrix`: 5.11, from 2021/02/22 :-)

Comment: Sure, thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you share how did you install the version 5.11, from 2021/02/22 ?  I tried updated nicematrix with tlmgr (package manager of TexLive). However, it updated the package into the latest one which seemed to have bugs. I have no idea how to update the package into the certain version.

Comment: @吕和瑾, I use MikTeX and upgrade `nicematrix` to v 5.11 by help of MikTeX Console a week or so ago. So far I didn't have any problems with it.

Answer (score 6):

Just for the sake of variety, here's a solution that employs the machinery of the `siunitx` package -- specifically, the `S` column type -- to format the inner `array` environments. Observe that the numbers are not centered but are aligned on the (explicit or implicit) decimal markers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'bmatrix' env.
\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' column type
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}

\begin{document}
\[
a = \begin{bmatrix} 
    \left[\begin{array}{@{} T{3.0} T{2.0} c @{}} % array #1
       255 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{array}\right] & 
    \left[\begin{array}{@{} c T{2.1} T{2.1} @{}} % array #2
       0 & 94.5 & 94.5 \\
    \end{array}\right] \\[1.5\jot]
    \left[\begin{array}{@{} T{3.0} T{2.0} c @{}} % same format as array #1
       0 & 99 & 0 \\
    \end{array}\right] & 
    \left[\begin{array}{@{} c T{2.1} T{2.1} @{}} % same format as array #2
       0 & 0 & 9 \\
    \end{array}\right]
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is another solution without nicematrix, only with plain TeX tools:

```
$$
  \def\[{[&\kern-.9em } \def\]{\kern-.9em&]}
  \left[\matrix{
      \[ 255 & 0  & 0 \]   &   \[ 0 & 94.5 & 94.5 \]   \cr
      \[   0 & 99 & 0 \]   &   \[ 0 & 0    & 9    \]   \cr
  }\right]
$$
```

Answer (score 1):

With `spalign` package with several...adjustments.....

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{spalign}

\begin{document}
\[ a= \spaligndelims{[}{]} 
\spalignmat[c]{\spalignmat[c]{255 0 0} \spalignmat[c]{0 94.5 94.5}\\[-1em]; \spalignmat[c]{\phantom{0}0 99 0} \spalignmat[c]{0\phantom{\mkern1mu 0} 0\phantom{00} \phantom{0}9\phantom{0}}\\[.3em]}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]